# How to return all data in filter ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I use custom filter in `ng-repeat`:

```
item in filtered = (project.data.campaigns | filter:isStatus() | filter:isCategory()) | orderBy : 'created_at'
```

And filter:

```
 $scope.isStatus = function() {

            return function(item) {
                var status =  $scope.inArray($scope.filterObj.status, item.status);
                console.log(status);
                return status;
            };  
        };
```

How to to, that if `$scope.filterObj` is empty, then to return all items in `ng-repeat`?

Simple, if `filter:isStatus()` is false, then return all items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.isStatus = function() {
    return function(item) {
        // false if filterObj is null
        // since ECMAScript 5.1 you can also use Object.keys
        if ($scope.filterObj && Object.keys($scope.filterObj).length > 0) { 
            return $scope.inArray($scope.filterObj.status, item.status);
        }

        return item;
    };
};
```

Comment: It does not work, when I clear object `$scope.filterObj` I get it as: `{"status":[],"categories":[]}`

Comment: Well made, this is not "empty". as you said in your question.

Comment: I need to check as `$scope.filterObj.status.length > 0 ` it works, thank you

Comment: Glad to help ya